# Android | GoogleMaps - Merge or combine Circle Borders

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Today i saw an picture of an old game. It was an googlemaps based mmorgp, where you could build up your empire. To claim land, you easily builded an flagpole. But im not the best in describing things.

So lets get back to my question. They used googlemaps circles to mark the area of an building, like an flagpole. When a few of those flagpoles were build very close to each other, they merged their borders, that looked like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW7t5.jpg [Wanted to post picture, but stackoverflow image uploader was broken]

So as you can see those circles were "combined". When the border isnt drawn, it looks like they are one big polygon instead of 2 circles. But how to achieve something like that ? Heres how i create a circle :

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a circle in Sydney
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
 .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689))
 .radius(10000)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Until now i didnt found any way to merge or combine multiple circles... I didnt even found out how to make the circle border collide with another circle border. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks for your time and help !^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is calculating the point where those 2 or multiple circles meet each other.